# Cross-Compile Yesod app for aarch64 system on x86_64

Tags: haskell, ghc, yesod, haskell-stack

as can be inferred from the title my goal is to deploy my Yesod app to an aarch64 Ubuntu server (using Keter). For this I would like to do compilation on my x86_64 debian machine, where I also develop the app. Simply using `yesod keter` produces the keter-package correctly, but the executable will not run (since it is compiled for x86) and I could not find a way to set a compilation target anywhere.

I have tried using the `stack.yaml` `arch` setting, but this then lead to the download of aarch64 ghc, which can then (as one would expect) not be executed on my x86 machine.

This is also my first time deploying a webapp in general, so if I missed something easy do let me know, any help is much appreciated.